# SOAP server exception

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2013

I am accessing the share point lists via Sharepoint web services. while accessing the list collection I am getting this exception. Kindly assist me.

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
```

Here is my code:

```
 try
            {
                SPListService.ListsSoapClient client = new SPListService.ListsSoapClient();

                XElement element = client.GetListCollection();
            }

            catch (Exception ex) { }
```

This is my web config

```
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="ListsSoap">

          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">

            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" realm="" />

          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://abc:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap" contract="SPListService.ListsSoap"
        name="ListsSoap" />

    </client>
```

Comment: pass null as a parameter to ListsSoapclinet() and try

Comment: It throws the exception. Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: endpointConfigurationName

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working, but my security setting in the bindings is slightly different:

```
<binding name="ListsSoap">
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

This should work with your original code, as that is all I have in my code to make the connection.